# Is it possible to evaluate a variable inside a call read() in karate?

Tags: testing, karate

**demoType** is a variable and I want the content of this variable to be what is evaluated in the following expression:

```
* def call read(demoType)
```

On the contrary, it tries to evaluate the name of the variable and not its content.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as `def call`.

Maybe you were trying:

```
* call read(demoType)
```

Or:

```
* def temp = call read(demoType)
```

Make sure you are on the latest version of Karate. And read the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#call-vs-read